# Перезапись указателя

Tags: c++, указатели, память

Если я перезапишу указатель при помощи `new`, будет ли утечка памяти? Нужно ли мне как-то удалять предыдущее значение  в куче?

```
#include <iostream>
#include "word.h"


class Sent{
    public:
        Sent(){};

        Sent(std::string *words, int length){
            setWords(words, length);
        }

        ~Sent(){
            delete[] words;
        }

        void setWords(std::string *words, int length){ //если я использую этот сеттер 2+ раз.
            this->words = new Word[length]; // Я вот про это говорю.
        }


    private:
        Word *words;
};
```

Comment: Да, гарантированно будет утечка. А еще надо не забыть инициализировать указатель нулевым значением, а то может получится удаление мусора, и про конструкторы копирования перемещения.

Comment: @user7860670 Объект, на который направляет указатель удаляется так: delete *words ?

Comment: @user7860670 нулевое значение в конструкторе оглавлять, или есть какая-то хитрость?

Comment: `private:
        Word *words { nullptr } ;` - надо обязательно обнулить, а то будет падать прога.

Comment: Наверняка setWords получает лишний аргумент из за незнания, что первый хранит свой размер... Ну и чем интересовал этот вопрос?  Нормальные вопросы получают по шее, а  вопросы про азбуку плюсы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new`, `delete` и деструкторы - это продвинутые фичи. Их, конечно, нужно знать, но использовать обычно не нужно.

Если вам просто нужен список, берите `std::vector`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct Word
{
    std::string value;
};

class Sent
{
  public:
    Sent(const std::string *strings, std::size_t size)
    {
        words.reserve(size);
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
            words.push_back({strings[i]});
    }

  private:
    std::vector<Word> words;
};
```

Обратите внимание:

- `const` на параметре-указателе. Ставьте его, если не записываете ничего по указателю внутри функции, а только читаете.

  Вместо двух параметров - указателя и длины - можно взять один новомодный `std::span<const std::string>`.
- Заменил тип параметра-длины на `size_t` - так каноничнее.
- Убрал `setWords`, потому что вместо него можно просто написать `x = Sent(...);`.

---

Если хотите поупражняться с new - то да, у вас утечка.

Наивное решение - сначала сделать `delete[] this->words;`, а потом присваивать. Но это ломается, если `new` выбросит исключение. Поэтому правильно - сначала `new` и сохранить результат в другой указатель, а потом, если все нормально, `delete[]` и заменить указатель.

Еще - заменить `Word *words;` на `Word *words = nullptr;`, чтобы первый раз не словить краш из-за удаления мусорного указателя.

Еще - не забыть удалить копирующие операции

```
Sent(const Sent &) = delete;
Sent &operator=(const Sent &) = delete;
```

, чтобы нельзя было словить краш вот так:

```
Words a(...);
Words b = a;
```

Тут деструкторы `a` и `b` удаляют один и тот же блок памяти, что вызывает ошибку.

А с удаленными копирующими операциями, `b = a` просто не скомпилируется.

Или, если копировать класс все-таки хочется, то написать свои копирующие и/или перемещающие операции.

Comment: `words.push_back({strings[i]});` стоит заменить на `words.emplace_back(strings[i]);` чтобы не плодить временные объекты

Comment: @user7860670 Угу. Когда кланг поддержит инициализацию агрегатов круглыми скобками, тогда я начну советовать в таких ситуациях `emplace_back`.

Comment: Чтобы кланг перестал жаловаться в этом случае достаточно сделать для этого не-POD класса явный конструктор, а агрегаты оставить для POD типов.

Comment: Я думаю, что std:vector вещь классная, но мой массив в идеале меняется всего 1 раз в конструкторе. И, я лично думаю, что вектор будет весить больше чем обычный заурядный динамический массив.

Comment: @Льоха Да, на 16 байт больше (на 64-битной платформе). Но из него никогда не утечет память, и его можно заставить проверять индекс при обращении к элементу, и писанины намного меньше. Вот когда начнет не хватать памяти, тогда будете думать. Если эти 16 байт так жалко, есть еще `std::unique_ptr<Word[]>` - весит как сырой указатель, но освобождает память автоматически. Но не знает свой размер, поэтому его нельзя скопировать и нельзя заставить проверять индексы.

Comment: New/delete в любом случае не стоит использовать в обычном коде - используйте их только если пишете свой аналог `vector` и `unique_ptr` (свой контейнер или умный указатель) - им лучше быть отдельно от основной логики программы, чтобы использующие их классы занимались только управлением памятью и больше ничем.

Answer (score 1):

Да будет происходить утечка. Чтобы её не было тебе нужно проверять указатель
`words` на `nullptr`, если он не пустой, то освобождать память с помощью `delete`

```
void setWords(std::string* words, int length) { 
        if (this->words != nullptr) {
            delete[] this->words;
            this->words = nullptr;
            }
            this->words = new Word[length]; 
        }
```

Comment: Можно просто освобождать, если он нулевой, то просто ничего не будет делаться...

Answer (score 1):

В современном C++ редко возникает необходимость явно использовать сырые указатели. Для большинства сценариев есть готовые средства - умные указатели для управления памятью, обзоры массивов для передачи без копирования, которые избавят от проблем с утечками памяти, битыми указателями и добавят семантику владения ресурсами. Соответственно код может выглядеть примерно так:

```
#include "word.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <span>
#include <string>

class Sent
{
    private: ::std::unique_ptr<Word []> m_words;
    
    public: explicit
    Sent(void) noexcept
    :   m_words{}
    {
        return;
    }

    public: explicit
    Sent(::std::span<::std::string> const words)
    :   m_words{}
    {
        Set_Words(words);
        return;
    }

    public: 
    ~Sent(void) noexcept
    {
        return;
    }

    public: void
    Set_Words(::std::span<::std::string> const words)
    {
        m_words.reset(new Word [words.size()]);
        ...
    }
};
```

Comment: 1. Явное указание деструктора, даже пустого, вредно для здоровья - у вас пропадают перемещающие операции. 2. Забыли `const` в шаблонном аргументе `span`. 3. `new` стоит заменить на `std::make_unique` - чтобы не использовать его вообще нигде, и не думать, где это безопасно, а где нет.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat 1. Их и не должно быть. Скорее вредно не указывать деструктор, когда он есть. Я бы тут еще сразу объявил все копирующие / перемещающие конструкторы и операторы с `=delete`, однако и так громоздко получается. 2 Не забыл. 3. Это сомнительная и [не универсальная](https://godbolt.org/z/oW3hP1G6K) практика, при том добавляющая оверхед при сборке. Собственно сам посыл избавляться от явного выделения памяти сомнителен. А в ситуации, когда используется особый способ создания объекта и deleter явное создание объекта все равно остается.

Comment: 1 - Странно, зачем избавляться от перемещения, если его можно разрешить. 2 - Забыли, как и автор вопроса забыл `const` на своем указателе. Это если его сеттер не изменяет переданный массив, чего он по идее не должен делать.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat 1) *Если* когда-нибудь возникнет потребность в перемещении, то можно будет *явно* определить нужные конструкторы и операторы. Честно говоря, необузданное рвение компилятора в тихую генерировать конструкторы и операторы мне представляется одним из промахов в дизайне языка.